Is it safe to use a Corsair RM850 power supply with a 10A 250V adapter in a 220V region?
I recently bought a PC with a Corsair RM850 power supply in Chile, where I received a power cable rated 13A 125V. However, I live in Argentina, where the standard voltage is 220V. I have a 10A 250V adapter, but want to confirm if this setup is safe to use without damaging my PC





The label says that the PSU will accept 100V–240V, so yes, it will accept your 220V mains voltage without issues (it's literally within the range).
The cable, on the other hand, only has its insulation rated for up to 125V and therefore likely unsafe to use with 220V. Try to find another IEC cable (preferably one that doesn't need an adapter).

Thanks, ass well the cable says 105° and 300V, so I don't know, but I will make sure before I plug the pc

Ah, right, so it's only the connectors that are marked as rated for 125V only, not the cable itself? In that case it's probably not as bad, but honestly I'd still recommend finding a more suitable cable regardless (i.e. one where both the cable itself and the plugs are rated appropriately).
